# VGA connection issue

Tags: windows-8, vga, lg-monitor

Why am I unable to use a VGA cable to connect my LG IPSle23 60 HTz monitor to my PC?

I've read that it may be a resolutions issue, I don't even like Matrix!

Seriously though, it's driving me mad, I have ALL the latest drivers, updates and everything, and I'm trying to connect the monitor using the motherboard connector, there is no VGA option with my graphics card it seems, just what looks like a VGA connector but with more pins.

I can connect using the HDMI but really wanted to use VGA, I don't think it's anything to do with the operating system either (Windows 8) as it says it uses pretty much the same drivers etc as Windows 7.

It connects to a laptop via VGA, but my PC....no signal.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you can use HDMI why would you prefer not to? VGA is lower quality by comparison...

Comment: Even more so, with HDMI you maintain a digital signal from the PC through the cable to the monitor. With VGA the signal on the cable is analog, whereas both the computer and the monitor work with digital signals, so you needlessly introduce D/A-A/D conversion losses. @Mokubai

Comment: Hi Mokubai, I wanted to set up a dual display system, with my TV as a primary using the HDMI for that, and a VGA connect for my smaller monitor, I could use another HDMI, for both, but being as this is my first attempt at building a PC I just wanted to iron out any bugs, it's just frustrating that it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think can do it. You see you get a choice, motherboard graphics or graphics card graphics. I don't believe they can run at the same time. This same problem occurs when you attempt to put two graphics cards that aren't of the same generation ( might be architecture) together. They won't run together. My suggestion is if you have another port on your graphics card attempt to use that.

Comment: Wow no love? I'm pretty sure this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you Griffin It seems this may be the case, at least I'd like to think it is after researching the issues, and not that I did or am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @Dafydd This problem seems to come up quite often. In fact just on friday I had the same problem when a friend was trying to diagnose a computer.

Answer (score 0):

> just what looks like a VGA connector but with more pins

You should not have a VGA (D-sub) connector with more than 15 pins. 9 pin is common for 
serial.

Is it possible your laptop has a 9 pin serial port that you think is a VGA connector? It is not uncommon for newer laptops not to have VGA output.

Comment: I think they are DVI connectors, I have 2 on my graphics card and one for the main board.

The Laptop works fine with the VGA lead connected to what I believe was the VGA, wouldn't it be the case that a VGA cable shouldn't fit into any plug other than a VGA, or are you saying it will, and work,   but not actually be a 'VGA connection'?

I didn't force anything.